# STDOUT of hg commands running through hstart to a file?

Tags: mercurial

I am using hstart to hide command prompt window when hg command runs. I want to store stdout/stderr of hg commands in a file but it is not working..

**hg update >log.txt 2>&1**

This works but when I use it with hstart like

**hstart "hg update"> log.txt 2>&1""**

I get an empty log file.I tried changing sequence of 2>&1 befor log.txt but no success

Any ideas??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The problem is that Hstart is not a console application - there are no STDOUT/STDERR streams associated with it" (from [this thread](http://www.ntwind.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1565&sid=8069860a5add16d304842275736d2897)).

In the same thread they suggest doing something like:

```
hstart /NOCONSOLE /WAIT "hg update > log.txt 2>err.txt"
```

Hope it'll help.

PS: As you seem to be using Windows and want popups of completed commands or errors, have you tried [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/about.html), it seems quite nice to have a GUI which is integrated into explorer.